# Is it possible to combine $(this) with a non child element?

Tags: jquery, hide, this, show-hide

I have a list of `<divs>` with the same class. Within each `<li>` are two `<divs>`. I want to hide one `<div>` when the user hovers over the other `<div>`.

The issue I am having is that when I use the following code, every `<div>` with the class ".div_2" is hidden when I hover over ANY `<div>` with the class ".div_1".

I want it so only the `<div>` with the class ".div_2" is hidden when the user hovers over the  with class ".div_1" in that specific `<li>`

I cannot change the markup or the classes, and was wondering how I can achieve this. Could I combine `$(this)` with ".div_2"?

```
<li>
<div class="div_1"></div>
<div class="div_2"></div>
</li>    
<li>
<div class="div_1"></div>
<div class="div_2"></div>
</li> 
... 

$(document).ready(function(){
    // MEDIA GALLERY HOVER //

        $(".div_1").hover(
          function () { $(".div_2").hide(); },
          function () { $(".div_2").show(); }
        );

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `next` method, which selects the next sibling of the element or `siblings` method.

```
$(".div_1").hover(
    function () { $(this).next().hide(); },
    function () { $(this).next().show(); }
);
```

- [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // MEDIA GALLERY HOVER //

        $(".div_1").hover(
          function () { $(this).siblings(".div_2").hide(); },
          function () { $(this).siblings(".div_2").show(); }
        );

})
```

---

Or to make you code shorter - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/USMbU/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div_1").on("mouseover mouseout", function() {
        $(this).siblings(".div_2").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div1').on('mouseover',function() { $(this).siblings('.div2').css('display','none'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".div_1").hover(
      function () { $(this).siblings(".div_2").hide(); },
      function () { $(this).siblings(".div_2").show(); }
    );
```